# Woocommerce minimum order total based on user roles

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I'm using a snippet code from Woocommerce [Minimum Order Amount](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/minimum-order-amount/) to set a minimum order total. But I would like to set different minimums per user role.

I have some custom user roles: `wholesale_prices`, `wholesale_vat_exc`, and `distributor_prices`. I want to make the code to work based on use roles with different minimum amounts for each role.

Here is my code:

```
// Minimum order total

add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
 
function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    // Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
    $minimum = 300;

    if ( WC()->cart->subtotal < $minimum ) {

        if( is_cart() ) {

            wc_print_notice( 
                sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' , 
                    wc_price( $minimum ), 
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )
                ), 'error' 
            );

        } else {

            wc_add_notice( 
                sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' , 
                    wc_price( $minimum ), 
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )
                ), 'error' 
            );

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please mention the source in your question if you are using pre-existing code - https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/minimum-order-amount/.

Comment: It's more than a year ago I paste that code In my function file, I really don't remember where I get it from but will try my best to search next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Wordpress conditional function `current_user_can()` like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    // minimum order value by user role
    if ( current_user_can('distributor_prices') )
        $minimum = 3000; 
    elseif ( current_user_can('wholesale_prices') )
        $minimum = 1000;
    elseif ( current_user_can('wholesale_vat_exc') )
        $minimum = 600;
    else 
        $minimum = 300; // default

    if ( WC()->cart->subtotal < $minimum ) {

        if( is_cart() ) {
            wc_print_notice( sprintf( 
                'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' , 
                wc_price( $minimum ), 
                wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )
            ), 'error' );
        } else {
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( 
                'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' , 
                wc_price( $minimum ), 
                wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )
            ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes on functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Do I need to create another function like this: 

`function wc_minimum_order_amount_distributors() {
if ( ! current_user_can('distributors') )
        return;

    // Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
    $minimum = 5000;` 
 
in order to set different minimum for distributors user role?

Comment: @HuseinYuseinov Updated… so you have a different amount by user role.

Comment: Thanks, you are the best!

Comment: Is it possible to set a different minimum order total for the first order of the specific user role and the order after the first one?